# I am having some trouble programming this !/bin/sh code into a file on ubuntu?

Tags: programming

I am new to Ubuntu and programming programs in general. I am supposed to edit this code into an Ubuntu file called ps1_script for an assignment for class. #!/bin/sh. However I am having some trouble putting the code into the file. What am I supposed to type in order to have the code be programmed into the file?

```
#!/bin/sh curl --head --silent https://www.reddit.com
```

Comment: Did they mention what text editor to use?

Comment: You need to put the curl statement on it's own line. Then make the file executable by chmod u+x.

Answer (score 2):

Open a text editor where you want your file to me - in your case the gui one would be a better choice - the default in ubuntu is called text editor, but for the purposes of the question I'll use nano since I don't have a gui text editor handy. For text editor, it should be almost exactly the same as with notepad. Open an instance, copy your code in and save it. If you do this, skip to the last line

Open up a terminal window and type in nano and hit enter.

Your command needs to be 2 lines actually, the #!/bin/sh tells the command processor what shell to use

[image]

Once this is done hit ctrl-x

[image]

Hit Y

[image]
It'll ask you for your file name - fill that in and hit enter.
[image]

The file *won't* be executable once its saved. You either need to change its permissions with `chmod +x ps1_script` - then you can run it directly or use the shell to run it `sh ps1_script`

Comment: Scripts can be run without the prefix sh. @Journeyman Geek

Comment: You can run scripts without the +x with running the sh command explicitly and feeding it the script as an argument